# Does Android 11 restrict accessibility services from working in the lock screen?

Tags: java, android

On Android 11 the Accessibility service doesn't turn on unless the user unlocks the lock screen. On previous Android versions the Accessibility service turns on as soon as the device is on. Is this a new restriction with Android 11, meaning does Android 11 prevent Accessibility services from being enabled until the lock screen is gone? And if it is then is there a way to circumvent this restriction?

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem with android 9 and 7.1 but android 11 device worked even the screen is locked.

Comment: I figured out that it was always on display while debugging which make android 11 work when locking. In fact any version of android will not work with accessibility service while phone is locked